# NServiceBus - Allocating Every class in every assembly to Endpoint From Sender

Tags: nservicebus

From the sending web application, NServiceBus is scanning and allocating every type to the endpoint.  This is consuming about three minutes, which then times-out the transaction.  I've tried configure.with(assemblies) to restrict assemblies that is scans, and i've tried the 'convention over configuration' unobtrusive configure.definingas methods to restrict message implementations.  We are migrating from an older version to the latest, so we are still using the IMessage implementation conventions.

Here's my bus.start code in the sender

I'm working on fumes ... I'd really appreciate some help.

```
//hack for the moment
string dir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/");
dir = Path.Combine(dir, "bin");
TraceDirect("Shared", System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information, dir);
System.Reflection.Assembly[] asss = { System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(dir, "myfirst.dll")), System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(dir, "mysecond.dll")) };

try
{



    using (TransactionScope ambient = new TransactionScope( TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
                    {
                        theMagicBus = NServiceBus.Configure.With(asss)
                        .DefineEndpointName("app")
                        .DefiningMessagesAs(t => typeof(IMessage).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                        .DefiningCommandsAs(t => typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                        .DefiningEventsAs(t => typeof(IEvent).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                        .DefaultBuilder()
                        .XmlSerializer()
                        .MsmqTransport().TransactionTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                        .IsTransactional(true)
                        .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                        .UnicastBus()
                        .ImpersonateSender(false)
                        .Log4Net<NServiceBusAppender>(a => { a.Name = "Shared"; })
                        .CreateBus()
                        .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());}}
```

And here is my Config

```
<MsmqTransportConfig NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"  />
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error"/>
  <UnicastBusConfig>
        <MessageEndpointMappings>
            <add Messages="myfirst" Endpoint="endpoint"/>
                <add Messages="mysecond" Endpoint="msgsvcpubinputqueue"/>
         </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
</MsmqTransportConfig>
```

Comment: What is the transaction scope for?

Answer (score 2):

From your code sample it's not entirely clear where the bus initialization code is, but it *looks* to me like you're initializing the bus on every request in your web service. Please don't do that! ;)

NServiceBus is designed to be initialized *once* at application startup, before you start doing any work. And then it will happily stuff itself into an IoC container of your choice, or just let you keep the resulting `IBus` around yourself for the duration of the application lifetime.

Comment: Exactly. Please initialize the bus in the global asax file and provide it to your controlers by using DI mechanism. If you don't have a DI container you could also use a static Lazy<IBus>

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I stripped the code out of its context; it is only called once on app startup.  That still doesn't explain why it is ignoring my convention.

Comment: Why do you have a `TransactionScope` around the initialisation?